# Build a dll that will work on any .net framework

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-framework-version

Is it possible to create a dll that will work on any version of .net framework? If yes, How?

Comment: Build it at the lowest version you need to support.

Comment: *any* version of the framework? So you want it to work on .NET 1.0 which means you won't be touching generics at all (nor find any system the supports it)? And it must work on .NET 52, despite the fact that that hasn't been invented yet and only works on quantum computers? Please come up with a *realistic* list of frameworks you actually need to work with.

Comment: I have created my class library using the template Class Library(.net standard2.0). But if I add this dll as a reference to another test application(Windows V4.0) its showing an error. _The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'_

Comment: .NET Standard 2 is **newer** than .NET Framework 4 - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-standard-2-0/ _And yes, that is confusing naming._

Comment: You can add multiple target frameworks to a project

Comment: Docs for multiple target frameworks https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/frameworks

Comment: Thanks Sir Rufo. I think I have already gone through it. As i am a newbie to .net, let me have a discussion with my team here about this. And get back soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile your Class, you get an .dll
For the Version, you have to compile at the first .NET Version.

In love with the JITer you can use this .dll in other .NET Languages.

Comment: Other language is fine. I want it to work on any **Frame Work version** of .net